# Where is the right place to ask about a data format name?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to find the name of a data format that I cannot recall the name and details of.

It is currently posted here: *[What is the name of this data format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910921/what-is-the-name-of-this-data-format?noredirect=1#comment80768492_46910921)*, but it doesn't seem to be the right place. Stack Overflow seems to be used to discuss more concrete questions.

Is there a place to ask about a vague data format?

The below quotes the original question:

> This may be a bad question but I really want to find back the data format name. I cannot recall the example though.
>
> I remember I saw it on wiki.c2.com but cannot find it again (tried to search on the site).
>
> It can represent nested 'object' (tree and/or array) like JSON but it's more lightweight and more easy to parse.
>
> It used [] if I remember correctly. It can contain integers, floating number, string, and also binary data (without escaping, the length is stated before the blob).
>
> It is not JSON, BSON, Protobuf, MessagePack, YAML, TOML, XML. It is not popular, the name seems to contains 'H'.
>
> And it can be parsed correctly even when the items are reversed.

Comment: It is fortunate that I recalled where I first saw it, I've posted the answer in the original post in case it helps others https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911757/3156509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this belongs to the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) site.

It even has a [data-formats tag](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-formats) already.

When posting, please also include full example of the data otherwise it will be impossible to answer, no matter where you ask it.